# if input value equals specific text, display div

Tags: jquery, css, forms, text, input

I'm learning jQuery slowly but surely, so please excuse my ignorance. I did a lot of googling that resulted in the Frankenstein example below.

In this example, if the user enters "Kasey" into the `input`, I would like div#pete to have `display:block`.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var val = $("#fname").length;
if (val = Kasey) {
        $("#pete").css("display", "block");
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></p>
<p id="pete" style="display:none;" >Pete</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use **[`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup)** handler to listen `keyup` event. Inside that use `this.value` to get the value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fname").keyup(function() {
        if (this.value == "Kasey") {
            $("#pete").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $("#pete").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8mzgj/1/)</kbd>

**UPADATE :**

You can simplify the code as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fname").keyup(function () {
        $("#pete").css("display", this.value == "Kasey" ? "block" : "none");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

do this changes to your code

- add `val()` for getting value of an element
- use `==` operator in condition
- for comparing string you should add quotes like "Kasey"

Note : if u want do this on form load code like follows or add `keyup()` event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var val = $("#fname").val();
if (val == 'Kasey') {
        $("#pete").css("display", "block");
    }
 }); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function is reading the value of fname when the document loads and not after the user input.  Also, you are assigning the length to val when you should be assigning the value

```
var val = $("#fname").val();
```

Lastly your if statement needs the is equal to operator with is ==

```
if (val == 'Kasey')
```