# I want change text & background color in javascript if input text is Pending, Approved, Done, Finish, Cancel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I want to change text & background color in javascript if the input text is

```
New = > Orange color
Pending = > light green color
Approved = > Green color
Done = > Blue color
Cancel = > Red color
can somebody help me please!
```

Comment: input code is like this

<span class="r-lookup-value"> APPROVED </span>

Comment: Really hard to understand what you are doing when you done post code.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22110659/3825777

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on what is triggering the change. For example, if it was typing into an input then you could change the text color by condition. This example changes if the value of the input is approved, but you could apply the same logic to the other conditions.

```
<input oninput="changeColor(this)"></input>
<span id="colorInput" class="r-lookup-value"> APPROVED </span>


const changeColor = ({value}) => {
  if (value == "APPROVED") document.getElementById("colorInput").style.color = "green"
  else document.getElementById("colorInput").style.color = ""
}
```

Comment: my code is like this

<span class="r-lookup-value">Approved</span>

change color if the text is Approved then change to GREEN
change color if the text is Pending to Light Green
so on
or else keep it black color

Comment: The the function that determines the text color will have to be executed when the text changes, but as I can't see what is changing the text, I can't create this function. The example above is an example of the text changing based on an input, but it can be used for whatever your using and you can add other colors for other conditions if you need.